# No endpoint set for postgres-service

Tags: postgresql, minikube, kubernetes-service

I'm having a problem getting an endpoint for my postgres-service. I've checked the selector and it does seem to match the pod name, but I've posted both yamls below.

I've tried resetting Minikube and following the Kubernetes debugging instructions, but no luck.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

postgres-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: db0
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: somevalue
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: somevalue
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
              name: "somevalue-pgdata"
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: "/home/docker/pgdata"
          name: somevalue-pgdata
```

And then my postgres-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    service: postgres
```

And showing my services, and no endpoint:

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP    46m
postgres-service   ClusterIP   10.97.4.3    <none>        5432/TCP   3s

$ kubectl get endpoints postgres-service
NAME               ENDPOINTS   AGE
postgres-service   <none>      8s
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - modified service.yaml to point to app instead of service. For anyone else, this is the working version:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres
```